# How to view SSIS package others created?

Tags: ssis

I saw some SSIS pacakges done previously by others that are used for scheduled jobs on SQL Server Agent. How do I open the SSIS package and view the content? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have Business Intelligence Development Studio installed? You can open the DTSX files using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open it in SSMS as well as Visual Studio. BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio) and SSMS are both actually Visual Studio and will do this.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response! I need to find the .DTSX file to open it, right? I only have the deployed filed on the server...